# Getting a picture from MS Access in to a picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi  I have used the code below to save  images to my database,

but now I want to know how I can get the picture from the database to a PictureBox

can you please help me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofdFoto.ShowDialog();
    string i = ofdFoto.FileName.ToString();
    pbxFoto.ImageLocation = i;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbConn.Open();
    string querys = "INSERT INTO Fruits (Name, Picture) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "','" + ImageToByte(pbxFoto.Image) + "')";
    OleDbCommand cd = new OleDbCommand(querys, dbConn);
    cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbConn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Picture saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox p =new PictureBox();
        p.ImageLocation = ofdFoto.FileName.ToString();
        p.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

See if this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static Bitmap BytesToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
        return img;
    }
}
```

and set to [`PictureBox.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) property:

```
pictureBox1.Image = BytesToBitmap(byteArray);
```

Comment: I have the code to convert the image from Byte to a image, but how can I get it into a picturebox.

Comment: Thank you and how do I get the picture from my database